# Angular How to get result from http get request

Tags: angular, asynchronous, httprequest, get-request

**What i try to do :**

- Send a get request with token in the header to a server
- Make the server send back false or true depending on the token
- Then depending on the response from the server i let the user acces to a page or not

**What i am struggling with:**

I challenged to get back result from server but i can't find how to exploit it due to asynchronous request

Here is my code:

```
isTokenValid(token: string) : boolean {

    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Authorization': token
        })
    };


    this.httpClient
    .get<boolean>('http://localhost:8080/getValueWithToken', httpOptions)
    .subscribe(
    (response) => {
        this.responseFromServer = response;
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log('Error:', error);
    }
    );

    /*
    while(this.isResponseReceived == false){
    }*/

    return this.responseFromServer;
}
```

**Problem is that** the return line is executed before this.responseFromServer = response; so I dont know how to return this.responseFromServer :(

Here is where i use the isTokenValid function :

```
canActivate(
route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> |boolean {

  //console.log(this.tokenService.isTokenValid(route.params['token']));


  if(this.tokenService.isTokenValid(route.params['token']) == true) {
    return true;
  } else {
    this.router.navigate(['/errorToken']);
  }}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: If you're using real tokens, you should use [`@auth0/angular-jwt`](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt), which can simply decode your token and check if it's valid. This would avoid an HTTP call to your backend ...

Comment: I am using jjwt in my backend(Spring/Java) to create token, but i am a lil bit confused with ur answer, is it not the backend role to check the token ? only backend know the secret key

Comment: No, the token is simply a string built with a signature. You can for instance copy your token and paste it **[there](https://jwt.io/)** and see what it contains. With my comment, what happens is that if the token is expired or it can't be decoded, then you have an invalid token.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I found:

In the first file:

```
isTokenValid(token: string) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Authorization': token
        })
    };

    this.httpClient
        .get<boolean>('http://localhost:8080/getValueWithToken', httpOptions)
        .subscribe(
            (response) => {
                resolve(response);
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log('Error:', error);
                reject(error);
            }
        );

    });
}
```

And then in the second file:

```
async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot)  {


  this.reponse = await this.tokenService.isTokenValid(route.params['token']); 

  if(this.reponse)
    return true;
  else
    this.router.navigate(['/errorToken']);
```

}

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

```
isTokenValid(): Promise<boolean> {

    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {

    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Authorization': token
        })
    };

    this.httpClient
        .get<boolean>('http://localhost:8080/getValueWithToken', httpOptions)
        .subscribe(
            (response) => {
                resolve(response);
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log('Error:', error);
                reject(error);
            }
        );

    });
}
```

Then

```
this.tokenService.isTokenValid(route.params['token']).subscribe(
result : boolean => {
    if (result == true)
        return true;
    else
        this.router.navigate(['/errorToken']);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer but it doesn't seems to work, here is what i get when I enter the URL "http://localhost:8080/getValueWithToken"

Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined at ...

Comment: Oh, right. You have to change isTokenValid as well to return a Promise<boolean>.

Comment: Not possible to suscribe to a promise. 
I found a solution thanks to you and promises (I posted it)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just return in the HTTP call?

```
return this.httpClient
.get<boolean>('http://localhost:8080/getValueWithToken', httpOptions);
```

And then subscribe in the component or wherever, and listen to the value + error? In the service just return observable. But if you don't want that then just return in the subscription in the service such as :

```
    this.httpClient
         .get<boolean>('http://localhost:8080/getValueWithToken', 
         httpOptions).subscribe(value=>{
               return value;
        }, error=>{// do something with error });
```